# Strange behaviour in Java concurrency using no synchronization

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

In **Java Concurrency in Practice** there is a sample that made me confused:

```
public class Novisibility {
    private static boolean ready;
    private static int number;

    private static class ReaderThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            while (!ready) {
                Thread.yield();
            }
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("0");
        new Thread(new ReaderThread()).run();
        System.out.println("1");
        number = 42;
        System.out.println("2");
        ready = true;
        System.out.println("3");
    }
}
```

I can understand reordering makes the loop to never break, but I can't understand why "1", "2" and "3" are never printed to console. Could any body help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't spawn a new thread but run it in the current one. Use the `start()` method instead.

Since you `run()` executes on the main thread and that method runs in an endless loop you'll never reach the `System.out.println()` statements (and neither do you reach `ready = true;`).

From the JavaDoc on `run()`:

> If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.

And `start()`:

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.